# It is possible to cut an image of ItextSharp.Text.Image?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, pdf, itext

I'm creating a pdf file from an large image, but my image is too large, and it does not fit in the only page. then i need split this image to create more pages.
any idea?

```
 public FileResult ResultadoParaPdf(string file)
        {

            string fileStringReplace = file.Replace("data:image/png;base64,", "");
            var image = Convert.FromBase64String(fileStringReplace);


            const int HorizontalMargin = 40;
            const int VerticalMargin = 40;

            using (var outputMemoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (var pdfDocument = new Document(PageSize.A4, HorizontalMargin, HorizontalMargin, VerticalMargin, VerticalMargin))
                {
                    iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter pdfWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDocument, outputMemoryStream);
                    pdfWriter.CloseStream = false;

                    pdfDocument.Open();

                    PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(1);
                    table.WidthPercentage = 100;
                    Image img = Image.GetInstance(image);
                    img.WidthPercentage = 100;
                    PdfPCell c = new PdfPCell(img, true);
                    c.Border = PdfPCell.NO_BORDER;
                    c.Padding = 5;
                    c.Image.ScaleToFit(750f, 750f);
                    table.AddCell(c);
                    pdfDocument.Add(table);

                    pdfDocument.Close();

                    byte[] created = outputMemoryStream.ToArray();

                    outputMemoryStream.Write(created, 0, created.Length);
                    outputMemoryStream.Position = 0;

                    return  File(created, "application/pdf", "teste.pdf");

                }
            }
}
```

Comment: You can not truly cut that image using itext classes. What you can do, though, is defining a clipping path before adding the image. This way only a part of the image is visible even though the whole image is there.

Comment: Any code reference for this please?

Comment: what you need? @TechTurtle

Comment: and code reference on how to achieve  clipping path before adding the image

Comment: My solution to this problem is another, I received an image in base64, cut it into equal size, I created a table with itext sharp and was dividing into cells.
   if you prefer I can send you my method. @TechTurtle

Comment: Yes, please. As I am going through the same approach.

Comment: @TechTurtle i send you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121091/discussion-between-techturtle-and-alisom-martins).