# Splitting image in ITextSharp

Tags: c#, itext

In my C# code, I am receiving a base64 image string.

We need to generate pdf from the same, however, the image may not fit in one page and so we have to split it accordingly.

Does anyone know any reference for dynamically splitting image in itextsharp?

```
iTextSharp.text.Image image = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(imageByte);
            float width = image.ScaledWidth;
            float height = image.ScaledHeight;
            float usedHeight = 0;

            iTextSharp.text.Rectangle page = new iTextSharp.text.Rectangle(1000, 2000);

            using (var outputMemoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (var pdfDocument = new Document(page))
                {
                    iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter pdfWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDocument, outputMemoryStream);
                    pdfWriter.CloseStream = false;

                    pdfDocument.Open();

                    PdfContentByte canvas = pdfWriter.DirectContentUnder;
                    while (usedHeight <= height)
                    {
                       canvas.AddImage(image, width, 0, 0, height, 0, -height / 2);
                        pdfDocument.NewPage();
                        usedHeight += 2000;
                    }
```

Comment: This is explained in the [official documentation](http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/how-show-image-large-dimensions-across-multiple-pages). You'll discover that many of the questions you wanted to ask are already answered there.

Comment: Thank you Bruno, I tried running the code but facing multiple issues. the "image.getScaledWidth()" and "image.getScaledheight()" does not seems to be exist for Image object ( - I suppose that it is iTextSharp.text.Image class).

Comment: You need to port the Java to C#. `Document.Open` is not accessible because you need `document.Open()` not `document.Open`. Also: in Java, you have getters and setters, like `getScaledWidth()`; in C#, getters and setters often are used as properties, for instance `image.ScaledWidth`. Don't use these differences as an excuse to ask a duplicate question.

Comment: The code seems to be assuming that we have to generate 4 pages. However, in my case the image is dynamic. Hence, I need to calculate the height of rectangular portion. I tried the code (provided in original question) but it isn't working:

Comment: Er... yes that code is a proof of concept that distributes the image over four pages. If you know how to distribute the image over 4 pages, it's a no-brainer to adapt the code so that it makes a decision based on the size of the image and the size of the page. Unless you aren't a developer. Are you a developer? If yes, you can answer the question yourself by adapting the example. If not, you are doing a job that should be done by someone else.

Comment: Why did you add this: `pdfWriter.CloseStream = false;` This is the second time I see someone do this. What made you think that's a good idea? That can't work. Tell me where you found this, because I really want to know who is misleading people into using this!

Comment: from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37734347/it-is-possible-to-cut-an-image-of-itextsharp-text-image

Comment: I tried to achieve this (see the updated code in question) however, I am unable to find much of the help on AddImage function. I tried few other options but not working. Yes, I am a developer, however, I tried to avoid re-inventing the weel. If you already have an example then it's good, else I will figure it out. Thank you.

Comment: Further to discussion, the question in official documentation doesn't ask to go only for 4 pages. If you are a developer then why should provided official solution which is bound to 4 pages?